# Sql select from row sum to column

Tags: sql, select, sum

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
 Itemcode | DocType  |  Qty     |
------------------------------------------------------------------
100011    | FA       | 100      |
100011    | FA       |  50      |
100011    | AJN      |  10      |
100011    | FA       | 100      |
100011    | AJN      | 50       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

need result

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
 Itemcode | FA       | AJN  |
------------------------------------------------------------------
100011    | 250      |   0      |
100011    | 0        |  60      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: If your question is "how to sum Qty based on DocType column using Select?" - should appear in your title & body of question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81b4a7/3).

```
select
    Itemcode,
    sum(case when DocType = 'FA' then Qty end) as FA,
    sum(case when DocType = 'AJN' then Qty end) as AJN,
from yourTable
group by
    Itemcode
```

Comment: Artigo FA AJN
100011 NULL NULL
100012 NULL NULL
100013 NULL NULL

Comment: Both field  returns null

Comment: @infotech.ang here is the example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81b4a7/3.  You can check your data type for `Qty` field.

Comment: [Quantidade]    decimal(28,10)

Comment: I have provided an example , I do not know which SQL engine you are running.

Comment: i am using MS SQL 2014, [Quantidade] decimal

Comment: Thank you Zealous, its working now , thank you so much